# How to change initial angle of rigid body Hinge Constraint?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

My scene is a toggle of sorts that a ball falls on. A rigid body hinge constraint allows the toggle to pivot and a limit within the constraint keeps it within about 25 degrees to either side.

I want the hinge/toggle to start to one side at the beginning of the simulation, but rotating it in object mode also affects the limits. How can I offset the initial rotation?
(Blender 2.80)